# Run server in background in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Unfortunately, at the moment, I cannot use docker-compose. And I have to get Google Cloud Proxy running in a Docker container. But it doesn't run in the container, as MySQL is unable to connect to Google Cloud SQL.

Keep in mind, I was able to connect outside of the container on my machine. So that's how I know the connection works.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy \
    && chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

RUN ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=project_placeholder:region_placeholder:instance_placeholder=tcp:3306 -credential_file=service_account.json &

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"
```

How can I configure it so Google Cloud Proxy runs?

Comment: How does the command which you use to run this container look? You should add it to the question.

Comment: Does it work if you change it to CMD instead of RUN for the cloud_sql_proxy?

I'm definitely not a Docker expert, but my understanding is that RUN is a build-time directive, and executes within a given layer, not at the container run-time level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RUN directive executes at build time so your CMD only start `node` process, that is why you are not able to connect because the proxy process is not running at all.

One way is to start both processes from `entrypoint` but you should know that in such case if proxy down due to some reason your container will still keep running as the main process is nodejs of the container.

Change the entrypoint to

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=project_placeholder:region_placeholder:instance_placeholder=tcp:3306 -credential_file=service_account.json &  npm start" ]
```

Comment: Is this approach better than supervisord?

Comment: In this case at least you container will know about node process  and container will take care of it  while in  supervisord, supervisord will responsible for both process and your container will just look for supervisord. So both have different pros and cons

Comment: I am deploying to AWS ECS via AWS CodeDeploy. I am just looking for the one most reliable during deployment. I do have health checks for the Targets in the Target Groups. So containers will not be deployed if health checks do not pass. THe health check is an endpoint in Express app that returns 200 ok.

Comment: In case of ecs as it have health check so first approach will work fine as if any proces down and health check failed  so Schuler will restart the container

Comment: Nice, this worked in the Docker image on my local computer. Now I will try deploying to ECS and hopefully it still works. Should I open up security groups for port 3306? Or will the proxy use port 80?

Comment: Not sure about the port but you can open port on which proxy is listening